# Path issues in JUnit testing with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code, io, path

I'm experiencing some problems with generating tests containing absolute paths with JUnit in VSC.

The following two variables writtenFilePath and generatedFilePath both contain the same identical String when I print them in the terminal. However they produce different outcomes when used in a JUnit test.

```java
private String writtenFilePath = "/home/$USER/Desktop/S2/src/test/test1.in";
private String generatedFilePath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().concat("/src/test/test1.in");
```

writtenFilePath produces the desired outcome when used in a test while generatedFilePath does not as the test cannot access the file.

Below is the error prompt from the following JUnit test, testing that the two Path Strings are equal.

```java
@Test
public void identicalFilePathsAreEqual() {
    assertEquals(writtenFilePath,generatedFilePath);
}
```

```
**org.junit.ComparisonFailure:**

**expected:**
/home/$USER/[Desktop/S]2/src/test/test1.in

**but was:**
/home/$USER/[.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/c1a1302e27095d0a416037f60c4e3677/redhat.java/jdt_ws/S2_a43208c]2/src/test/test1.in
```

The test I'm trying to run: (Works as intended with the writtenFilePath, fails with the generatedFilePath)

```java
@Test
public void sizeIsSixFromTest1() throws IOException {
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(readLineByLineJava8(generatedFilePath).getBytes()));
    Lexer lex = new Lexer(System.in);
    assertEquals(6,lex.howManyTokens());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing

Customize test configurations

search in preferences in VSC for java.test.config

open settings.json

set workspacefolder with

```
"java.test.config": {
"workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

then it should work... had the same issue yesterday and found this solution today... and it works ;)